# TraceEventSession usage in ServiceFabric application raises insufficient resource error

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, etw

I have a State-full service fabric application running in a cluster.. I have about 20 State-full applications running in the same cluster. i have used TraceEventSession for correlation purposes. My cluster is having 10 nodes. When i deploy an application i am able to see the TPL session running active in Performance Monitor. When the number of application deployed in the cluster increased i started receiving the error specified

> Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800705AA)
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800705AA): Insufficient
>   system resources exist to complete the requested service. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800705AA)    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Session.TraceEventSession.EnableProvider(Guid
>   providerGuid, TraceEventLevel providerLevel, UInt64 matchAnyKeywords,
>   TraceEventProviderOptions options)    at
>   TestApp.Service.Program.Main() in
>   C:\Agent_work\12\s\TestApp\TestApp.Service\Program.cs:line
>   61

this is the code i wrote in program.cs to enable the tpl session

```
session = new TraceEventSession("TestApp_TplSession");  
session.EnableProvider(TplEtwProviderTraceEventParser.ProviderGuid, TraceEventLevel.Verbose,
                        (ulong)TplEtwProviderTraceEventParser.Keywords.TasksFlowActivityIds);

session.EnableProvider(ServiceEventSource.Current.Name);
```

I am not sure of how many state full service application will be deployed in the same cluster. How will i get rid of this error??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows has a limit of 64 ETW sessions that can be running concurrently.  Consider using a single stateless app running on every node to create a single session.

Comment: So do you mean that all the other applications deployed in the cluster should use the session created by the stateless session so that much of the memory can be utilized??

Comment: I am monitoring correlation in my application to track the flow of request.. can you tell me if the activityId and relativeActivityId would repeat for different requests??

Comment: For what it's worth, I've noticed this even when running a single listener e.g. PerfView or Visual Studio's Diagnostic Events window. They don't seem to always clean up after themselves so eventually a reboot is required just to start a single new session.

From the code above, at the very least, TraceEventSession is IDisposable and should be disposed.

As ETW is machine-wide, I think Matt's advice was to run a single additional stateless service with an ETW listener that takes all events from the node and pushes them somewhere. Consider using Microsoft Diagnostics EventFlow for this.